# Converting a 2D matrix into a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I am facing a problem while converting a given 2D matrix containing both invalid and valid points into a graph with only valid nodes. The problem goes like this.
I have a 2D matrix like

```
# # # # #
# . C C #
# S # # #
# . . E #
# # # # #
```

I want to find the shortest distance from S to E keeping in mind that I have to cover all 'C' and '#' acts as a wall and '.' acts as free path. 
Now I want to convert this matrix into a graph containing only the valid nodes. 
Kindly help me out.

```
n = number of nodes
for i=1 to n: for j=1 to n: d[i][j]=INF
 for k=1 to n:
   for i=1 to n:
    for j=1 to n:
        d[i][j] = min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j])

shortest = INF
for each permutation a[1],a[2],...a[k] of the 'mustpass' nodes:
  shortest = min(shortest, d['start'][a[1]]+d[a[1]][a[2]]+...+d[a[k]]['end'])
print shortest
```

Comment: I am trying to do it in Java. Still not up with the approach.

Comment: So the idea is to get a list of all passable Elements?

Comment: Can you include your attempt in your question?

Comment: Approach: Finding the all pair shortest path in the resulting graph. Floyd Warshall (I guess). The maximum number of nodes can go to 1000.  But the maximum number of C nodes is 20. What would be the best algorithm for this.

Comment: You will have to at least show an attempt at solving the problem youself before people will help you

Comment: I am unable to do the further steps as I need a graph on which I will implement the approach. Thanks

Comment: [link](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/) might be interesting

Comment: Not sure if this is what your looking for. But for actually creating the graph you should take a look at JFreeChart. But thats just a library for drawing graphs, it wont help with the algorithim for sorting the nodes.

Answer (score 5):

A 2d matrix of the characters is a perfectly fine graph representation for this problem.

Each matrix element (i,j) is a node. Assuming you can only step East, West, North, South, there exist 0 to 4 undirected edges from this node to its neighbors (i +or- 1, j +or- 1) as determined by simply testing the character in each location.

You could also test for i,j values that are out of range (negative or too big), but if there is always a "wall" around the border as you have shown,  this is not needed. The wall serves as a [sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Building a general purpose structure to represent a graph embedded in a grid is a waste of time and memory.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a homework but for the sake of conversation (time/space complexity) I would do something different.  First I would create a Graph that only contains valid edges between nodes that can be a path (e.g. not a wall).  This minimize the space needed.  I won't use a matrix because it uses too much space in real graph (sparse) and the time complexity is ROW*COL (V^2 for a square matrix).

```
class Graph {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> edgeTo;

    Graph() {
        this.edgeTo = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
    }

    public int size() {
        return edgeTo.size();
    }

    public void addEdge(int v1, int v2) {
        add(v1, v2);
        add(v2, v1);
    }

    private void add(int from, int to) {
        if (!edgeTo.containsKey(from)) {
            Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
            s.add(to);
            edgeTo.put(from, s);
        } else {
            edgeTo.get(from).add(to);
        }
    }

    public Set<Integer> adj(int v) {
        return edgeTo.get(v);
    }
}
```

With this in-place the creation of the graph follows the idea of previous post,

```
    private Graph createGrap(char[][] matrix) {
    Graph g = new Graph();
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix[0].length; c++) {

            // skip this cells
            if (!isFreeCell(matrix[r][c])) {
                continue;
            }

            int id = createUniqueId(r, c);
            if (matrix[r][c] == 'S') {
                startVertex = id;
            } else if (matrix[r][c] == 'E') {
                endVertex = id;
            }
            createNeighbor(r, c, matrix, g);
        }
    }
    return g;
}

private void createNeighbor(final int r, final int c, final char[][] matrix2, final Graph g) {
    for (int row = -1; row <= 1; row++) {
        for (int col = -1; col <= 1; col++) {
            // avoid the center cell
            if (row ==0 && col == 0){
                continue;
            }
            // outside matrix
            if ((0 > c + col) || (c + col >= matrix2[0].length) || (0 > r + row) || (r + row >= matrix2.length)) {
                continue;
            }
            char value = matrix2[r+row][c+col];
            if (!isFreeCell(value)){
                continue;
            }
            int from = createUniqueId(r, c);
            int to = createUniqueId(row+r, col+c);
            g.add(from, to);
        }
    }

}

private boolean isFreeCell(char value) {
    return (value != '#' && value !='C');
}

private int createUniqueId(int r, int c) {
    return r * MAX_COL + c;
}
```

Now the only thing left is to find the Shortest Path...using BFS of this undirected-graph with no negative weighed edges...

```
private void findSP(Graph g) {
    if (g == null || g.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty or null graph");
    }

    if (g.size() == 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "graph's size must be greater than 1");
    }

    if (startVertex == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start vertex not found");
    }

    if (endVertex == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("End vertex not found");
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> sonToParent = bfs(g, startVertex, endVertex);

    Stack<Integer> path = new Stack<Integer>();
    for (int son = endVertex; son!= startVertex; son = sonToParent.get(son)){
        path.push(son);
    }

    path.push(startVertex);
    while (!path.isEmpty()){
        System.out.print(path.pop() + ", ");
    }
}

private Map<Integer, Integer> bfs(Graph g, int startVertex2, int endVertex2) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> marked = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> sonToParent = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    q.add(startVertex2);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        int v = q.poll();
        for (Integer s : g.adj(v)) {
            if (!marked.contains(s)) {
                marked.add(s);
                sonToParent.put(s, v);

                if (s == endVertex2) {
                    return sonToParent;
                }

                q.add(s);
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the graph, you have to generate a node for each non-wall space. Go through the 2D matrix (assuming it's just a char array) and create nodes and add edges:

```
nodes = new Node[matrix.length][matrix[0].length]; //instance variable

for ( int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ )
{
  for ( int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++ )
  {
    char type = matrix[row][col];
    if ( type != '#' )
    {
      Node n = new Node();
      nodes[row][col] = n; //constructor to determine type of node
      if ( type == 'S' )
        startNode = n;
      else if ( type == 'E' )
        endNode = n;

      findNeighbors(row, col); //assuming nodes and matrix variables are instance variables
    }
    else
      nodes[row][col] = null;
  }
}
```

With a 2D array of nodes, you can then go through and add neighbors with findNeighbors:

```
public void findNeighbors(int row, int col)
{
  for ( int r = -1; r <= 1; r++ )
  {
    for ( int c = -1; c <= 1; c++ )
    {
      try { 
        if ( matrix[row+r][col+c] != '#' ) 
          nodes[row][col].addEdge(nodes[row+r][col+c]);
      } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
    }
  }
}
```

Now, after all that code, you have a 2D array of Node objects that represent a graph. You could store the Start node in an instance variable to keep a handy reference to it and easily access its neighbors.

With the code I wrote, the Node class will need a method `addEdge(Node)` that adds the argument node to a list of nodes.

Comment: +1 I was writing similar answer. Though, I wouldn't make it `Node`'s responsibility to remember what type it is. Instead, I would store the start and end nodes in variables (possibly in an object) and the coverables in a set.

Comment: That's a better idea. I'll fix that in the code. Thanks for the +1!

Answer (score 0):

I would either create a node struct, or a node class. For example:

```
struct Node {
    node type;  //Indicate in some way if the node is a 'S', '.' or 'E'
    std::vector<Node> adjacentNodes;
}
```

As far as filling this data structure, I would start at the 'S' block. And make a recursive call kind of like:

```
Set alreadyVisited;

FillGraph(i,j,Node){
//    for all adjacent nodes, add them to Node's adjacentNodes.
//    add Node to alreadyVisited Set
//    for each of the adjacentNodes (i.e. any neighbor that isn't a wall.
//       if(adjacentNode is not in alreadyVisited)
//          FillGraph(adjaent-i, adjacent-j, adjacentNode);
}
```